# Verification of binomial coefficient congruence $\binom{jp}{j}\equiv j\binom{p}{j}\pmod{p^2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, congruences

Let $j\ge 1$ be an integer and $p$ prime.

Is it true that

$$\binom{jp}{j}\equiv j\binom{p}{j}\pmod{p^2}$$

**My work** No, take $j>p$, then the RHS is zero, while the LHS need not be $\equiv 0$. For example, for $p=3$ and $j=5$, I find $\binom{jp}{j}=3003\equiv 6\pmod{p^2}$.

However, is the claim true for $j\le p$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\binom{jp}{j} = \frac{jp}{j} \binom{jp-1}{j-1} = p \binom{jp-1}{j-1}$ and $j \binom{p}{j} = j \frac{p}{j} \binom{p-1}{j-1} = p \binom{p-1}{j-1}$. Now we want to show that $\binom{jp-1}{j-1} \equiv \binom{p-1}{j-1} \pmod{p}$.

Since $jp-i \equiv p-i \pmod{p}$, we have $$\binom{jp-1}{j-1} = \frac{(jp-1)\cdots(jp-j+1)}{(j-1)!} \equiv \frac{(p-1) \cdots (p-j+1)}{(j-1)!} = \binom{p-1}{j-1} \pmod{p}$$

Therefore $$\binom{jp}{j} = p \binom{jp-1}{j-1} \equiv p \binom{p-1}{j-1} = j \binom{p}{j} \pmod{p^2}. $$

**Comment.** $j \le p$ is used in the line expanding $\binom{jp-1}{j-1}$ because it makes sense only when the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: +1. Once you've brought it down to a congruence mod$~p$, you could also use [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) which gives: $\binom{jp-1}{j-1}\equiv\binom{j-1}0\binom{p-1}{j-1}=\binom{p-1}{j-1}$ when $j-1<p$. By the way, at the very end of your comment, you forgot to say "modulo$~p$".

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer now myself, but I like your solution, too.